# Secondary model to correct RNN-based photovoltaic power generation forecast: Useful and what model type?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting

I am currently working on forecasting short horizon photovoltaic (PV) power generation. My primary forecasting model is an RNN which aims to forecast the PV power generation from the current day until the end of the next day. My main features for this prediction task include weather forecasts and possibly seasonal information. The model is set to generate forecasts whenever new weather data is received, which is typically on a 3-hour interval.

During the course of a day, I also receive updates on the actual realized power generation every 15 minutes. Given these frequent updates, I'd like to consider the possibility of integrating a secondary model. The purpose of this secondary model would be to correct the predictions from the primary RNN model, especially when there's a significant deviation between the RNN's forecast and the actual realized values. The idea here is to potentially use the forecast from the RNN, the actual realized values, and the deviation between them to make a correction.

With this context:

- Would such a secondary correction model be a beneficial addition? Has anyone had success with a similar approach in any time series forecasting domain?
- If the idea is considered valid, what model types or architectures would be suitable for this kind of correction task?
- Are there other techniques or approaches to update and correct forecasts in real-time that I should consider?

Appreciate insights or references on this matter. Thanks in advance!